# How does one configure sibling Pedestal routes so that all are accessible when using :constraints?

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I am creating a toy Pedestal service intended to have the following resources:

- `/`
- `/movies`
- `/movies/today`
- `/movies/:iso-date` where `:iso-date` matches ####-##-##

The constraint for the last route is defined with the following snippet:

```
^:constraints {:iso-date #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"}
```

Whenever the route containing this constraint is present in the route table I am unable to GET its sibling route `/movies/today`; instead I am getting a "Not Found" response instead. When the constraint-having route is removed, however, a GET of `/movies/today` succeeds.

The Pedestal routes I have defined using terse format look like so:

```
(defroutes routes
  [[["/" {:get root-page}
     ["/movies" ^:interceptors [fetch-movies]
      {:get movies-page}
      ["/today" {:get movies-for-today-page}]
      ["/:iso-date" ^:constraints {:iso-date #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"}
       {:get movies-for-date-page}]]]]])
```

Have I constructed this route table correctly in order to achieve the routing behaviour that I want?

NB: Printing the compiled routes gives me the result that I would expect in that all of the routes are present the generated `:path-re` regexes match as expected at the REPL:

```
({:path-parts [""],
  :path-params [],
  :interceptors
  [{:name :foobar.service/root-page,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__7359 0x14501070 "io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__7359@14501070"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}],
  :path "/",
  :method :get,
  :path-re #"/\Q\E",
  :route-name :foobar.service/root-page}
 {:path-parts ["" "movies"],
  :path-params [],
  :interceptors
  [{:name :foobar.service/fetch-movies,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$on_request$fn__7401 0x2aa85cc4 "io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$on_request$fn__7401@2aa85cc4"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}
   {:name :foobar.service/movies-page,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__7359 0x30ffc3c0 "io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__7359@30ffc3c0"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}],
  :path "/movies",
  :method :get,
  :path-re #"/\Qmovies\E",
  :route-name :foobar.service/movies-page}
 {:path-parts ["" "movies" "today"],
  :path-params [],
  :interceptors
  [{:name :foobar.service/fetch-movies,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$on_request$fn__7401 0x2aa85cc4 "io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$on_request$fn__7401@2aa85cc4"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}
   {:name :foobar.service/movies-for-today-page,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__7359 0x3726fc3b "io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__7359@3726fc3b"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}],
  :path "/movies/today",
  :method :get,
  :path-re #"/\Qmovies\E/\Qtoday\E",
  :route-name :foobar.service/movies-for-today-page}
 {:path-parts ["" "movies" :iso-date],
  :path-params [:iso-date],
  :interceptors
  [{:name :foobar.service/fetch-movies,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$on_request$fn__7401 0x2aa85cc4 "io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$on_request$fn__7401@2aa85cc4"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}
   {:name :foobar.service/movies-for-date-page,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__7359 0x93fb20b "io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__7359@93fb20b"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}],
  :path "/movies/:iso-date",
  :path-constraints {:iso-date "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})"},
  :query-constraints {},
  :method :get,
  :path-re #"/\Qmovies\E/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})",
  :route-name :foobar.service/movies-for-date-page})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem in pedestal version 0.4.1-SNAPSHOT.

`(io.pedestal.http.route/router my-routes :linear-search)`

Use `:linear-search`, instead of `:prefix-tree`.